# eval() questions with traditional divide symbol (÷)

Tags: python, replace, eval, division

I have a lot of division questions to work out, which would have been done by now if they were written with "/", but the source is a school teacher not a programmer so the questions look like this:

> 346÷30=
>
> 432÷40=
>
> 94÷40=

clearly python does not like the divide symbol:

> eval(762÷80=) SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

and replace is just being daft:

```
text_file = open("...questions.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split('\n')
for line in range(len(lines)):
    lines[line].replace(u"\u00F7", "/")
    print(lines[line])
```

I originally tried it with the symbol:

```
text_file = open("...questions.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split('\n')
for line in range(len(lines)):
    lines[line].replace("÷", "/")
    print(lines[line])
```

but either way the results are

```
346÷30=
432÷40=
94÷40=
```

I'm really at a loss of what else to try, I don't want to go through it all manually replacing the division symbols just so that I can run eval() like I usually would.

Any advice, welcome, even/especially if there is another way around this problem.

Comment: Are you supposed to be using Python to compute this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`replace`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) returns the new string, so you must assign it:

```
lines[line] = lines[line].replace("\u00F7", "/")
```

While you're at it, you can clean up your code by a lot; use the `with` statement when you open a file and just iterate over the file to get lines:

```
with open("...questions.txt", "r") as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        line = line.replace("÷", "/")
        print(line)
```